# Como mudar de uma página para outra no React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Eae galera, estou iniciando no React Native, e estou desenvolvendo um App, para o meu TCC, este aplicativo é sobre Jogadores de Futebol, e tem uma tela que aparece uma lista destes jogadores, e coloquei um botão "Detalhes" que ao clicar gostaria que fosse para outra página chamada detalhesJogadores, tentei colocar o onPress para redirecionar mas não consegui, gostaria de uma ajuda para poder solucionar este problema

```
import {Text, View,StyleSheet,Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Detalhes from '../jogadores/detalhesJogadores';



export default class JogadoresLista extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.viewDentro}>
        <View style={styles.viewTop}>
          <Image source={this.props.imageUri} style={styles.imagem} />
            <View style={styles.viewBottom}>
                <Text style={styles.textoP}>{this.props.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textoP}>{this.props.posicao}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.botao} title="Detalhes" onPress={(Detalhes)}>
                  <Text style={styles.textoB}>Detalhes</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );  
}
}
```

Coloquei a foto para poder mostrar de uma melhor forma

[image: foto]

Comment: Eu implemento essa troca de páginas utilizando o ```react-navigation```: https://reactnavigation.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felipe, para navegação utilizo a lib

> react-navigation V4

Para que consiga navegar entre telas, depois de configurar as rotas pegue de dentro do this.props a propriedade navigation e utilize:

```
navigation.navigate('Rota', {parametros})
```